# Rails 4: Fontawesome causing AssetFilteredError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, font-awesome

I have a really simple Fontawesome setup:

**Gemfile**:

```
gem 'font-awesome-rails'
```

**applicaton.css**:

```
/*
 *= require font-awesome
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
```

When I start up my Rails server in development, I get the following error message:

```
Sprockets::Rails::Helper::AssetFilteredError in Home#index

Asset filtered out and will not be served: add `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( fontawesome-webfont.eot )` to `config/initializers/assets.rb` and restart your server
  (in ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/font-awesome-rails-4.2.0.0/app/assets/stylesheets/font-awesome.css.erb)
```

The line causing this issue is, obviously, the one that imports Fontawesome:

**application.html.erb**:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag('application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true) %>
```

I'm utterly confused as to how this is breaking now when it worked just a few days ago. I see that the last change to Fontawesome-rails on Github was about a month ago so I'm truly perplexed as to why this may not be working. Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: You have your answer in that error message: add `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( fontawesome-webfont.eot )` to `config/initializers/assets.rb` and restart your server

Comment: No, that can't be it. If I add that, it breaks with the same message telling me to add `fontawesome-webfont.woff`. If I add that, it breaks with the same message telling me to add `fontawesome-webfont.ttf`. If I add that, it breaks with the same message telling me to add `fontawesome-webfont.svg`. If I add that, it breaks with the same message telling me to add `query-ui/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png` and so on and so forth. This cannot possibly be the right solution

Comment: @Octopus-Paul that is not the solution. Others are also experiencing this apparently: https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails/issues/124

Comment: Ok, let us know when you find the solution.

Comment: Sure thing. Seems to be related to sprockets-rails v2.2.3 which was released today

Comment: Just updated my gems and now I have the same problem :D. Nice

Comment: You can downgrade or use a workaround as specified here: https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/issues/217  . Add this into assets.rb `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += [/.*\.png/, /.*\.ico/, /.*\.jpg/, /.*\.js/, /.*\.scss/, /.*\.eot/, /.*\.svg/, /.*\.woff/, /.*\.ttf/]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was reported as an issue with the sprockets-rails gem:

https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/issues/217

sprockets-rails v2.2.4 fixes this.